# Printing an 8ft X 4ft design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, image-format

So I have a friend who wants a vector image done for a wall print in their karate studio. But they want the image 8 ft high and 5ft long. Do you actually make a file that big then draw the design then print it? Or is their some way to make it so its smaller, but for printing, scale it up proportionally?

Comment: Please see this q+a: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4925/5746

Comment: Vectors can be scaled forever, so no need to worry about the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just work in some reasonable scale like 10% of actual. I do the same for large raster work but, obviously, increase the dpi accordingly.

Comment: For printing it, is their someway to scale it up? EDIT: I actually just looked at my printing settings, my guess is you print directly from illustrator and go to custom scale and scale it up.

Comment: You got it. I typically just give the printer my scale off the artboard and let them worry about how they want to get it to full size.