# How to design for large scale?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm interested to know the processes involved in designing for large scale output i.e. billboards/ banners.

What Illustrator/ Photoshop document size should I work with. Do I work in a scaled size of the final output version? What resolution do I use? If I'm to use photographed images, what resolution should they be?

Would appreciate all the help I can get on this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Ask your printer. Also see [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4925/23061) and [this one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/26354/23061)

Answer (score 2):

Usually the printer will have guidelines about picture resolution (for bitmap images like photographs), and you should double check with whoever is producing the final product.

Typically, I've see requirements of 150 dpi on raster images.

When I design large-scale items, I will work on a 1/10 scale mockup (to keep my file sizes reasonable) and after client approval will scale the piece up to actual size before submitting it to the printer. If I'm using any stock photography, I make sure to purchase images of sufficient size to scale up without pixelation. Vector images, of course, don't have these kinds of restrictions.

tl;dr **check with the printer, they will tell you what resolution they need in the final artwork**